# Extract value test from ["test"] in php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I know the title isn't describing the problem very well. I'm using laravel 5.4. What I would like to know is how I can remove the [""] when I print my file from my database.

From example in my database I have a column called file and in that column I have an item called ["book.pdf"].

What I would like is to remove the [""] so that I only have book.pdf

Comment: how are you currently printing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an accessor, to every time you call the `file` column remove the `['']`

1 - Go to your model

2 - Create an acessor:

```
class FooBar extends Model
{
    /**
     * Format the name to remove ['']
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFileAttribute($value)
    {
         if (preg_match('/\["([^"]+)"\]/', $value, $m) ) {
              return $m[1];   
         } 
         else {

         //return the original value
         return $value;

         }
    }
}
```

Now in your view, you just to call:

```
{{ $foo->file }}
```

and the output will automagically be formatted.

Comment: What a laravelian answer!

Comment: Oh, stop it you! http://i3.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/facebook/000/010/809/happy-oh-stop-it-you.jpg

Comment: But I think you totally forgot about the brackets in your regex. preg_match('/\\["([^"]+)"\\]/', $value, $m)

Comment: I just copied the regex from Love-Kesh here, I'll update my answer, thanks!

Comment: I'm getting `preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given` on the line that has `if (preg_match('/\["([^"]+)"\]/', $value, $m) ) {`

Comment: Try: preg_match('/\["([^"]+)"\]/', (string)$value, $m)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $str  = '["book.pdf"]';

//forward slashes are the start and end delimeters
//third parameter is the array we want to fill with matches
if (preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/', $str, $m)) {
    print $m[1];   
} else {
   //preg_match returns the number of matches found, 
   //so if here didn't match pattern
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given` on the line that has `if (preg_match('/\["([^"]+)"\]/', $value, $m) ) {`

Comment: Try $string=(string)$yourObject; then preg_match this using $string

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the same string, `[""]`, I would just use `substr($string, 2, -2)` to remove the characters.